# Reference file with JSON locators class

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have JSON data in my main file, lets call this main.py (this uses Selenium driver):

```
main.py

def get_user_data(browser):
    browser.get(JSON_URL)
    user_data = json.loads(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
    browser.back()
    return user_data
```

To get a value from this, I use:

```
name = user_data['name']
```

This works just fine. This is a larger program and I would like to have these locators in another file called locators.py using a class so if a locator changes, I just change it in one place:

```
locators.py

class UserDataLocators:
    NAME = user_data['name']
```

Now, the above fails because 'user_data' is not defined. I like this approach since I have other selenium locators in this file in a separate class. This may be a super simple fix, but how would I get the above to work so in my main.py file, I can import UserDataLocators and do the following:

```
from locators import UserDataLocators

name = UserDataLocators.NAME
```

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

@maxhaz So with what you wrote, it gave me an idea to maybe just use your UserData class to parse everything instead of just storing locators. Basically this is what I'm looking to accomplish. The user_data['name'] will get updated/changed as other modules interact with it. I'd like to store the user_data in locators.py and be able to access it and update it with the other modules, and after everytime it is update, each module can get the updated data.

For example, locators.py has the `user_data` as `None` to start since no browser is initiated. Main.py will be the first to interact with it and passes the browser to get the initial `user_data['name']` value. Module2.py will also import from locators.py and get that same `user_data` that main.py just updated. Module2 will update the `user_data['name']`. Once this happens, is this new `user_data['name']` now updated for main.py and locators.py?

```
#locators.py

user_data = None

class UserData:
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
        self.name = self.get_user_data()['name']

    def get_user_data(self):
        self.browser.get(JSON_URL)
        user_data = json.loads(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
        browser.back()
        return user_data

#main.py
import locators

locators.user_data = UserData(browser).name

#module2.py
import locators

## do something here that modifies the actual user data that gets pulled ##

locators.user_data = UserData(browser).name
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move the `get_user_data` function in the class:

```py
#locators.py
class UserDataLocators:
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
        self.name = self.get_user_data()['name']

    def get_user_data(self):
        self.browser.get(JSON_URL)
        user_data = json.loads(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
        browser.back()
        return user_data

#main.py
from locators import UserDataLocators
name = UserDataLocators(browser).name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the original question. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Although your code (Update 1) should work, it might not make the best usage of the class. Another way would be to add `user_data` as an instance attribute of the class UserData: `self.user_data = self.get_user_data()`. You would have one `user_data` variable per class instance.